# Watching in scope vs parent scope for the same value change - is there a difference?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I have a pretty basic question about Angular watches. Say I have following in the link function of my directive:

```
scope.$watch(function(){
    return element.isVisible();
  }, myFuncUponVisibleChange);
```

Is this going to be the same as:

```
scope.$parent.$watch(function(){
     return element.isVisible();
  }, myFuncUponVisibleChange);
```

In other words, is Angular watching for the visibility of the same element in both cases above?

Comment: Last sentence doesn't make sense. Could you reword it?

Comment: Thank you disso, I fixed the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both scope watchers watch on the same element, because `element` refers to particular object, and it was referenced in watcher function.

And yes, there is a substantial difference.

A lot of performance issues in AngularJS  are caused by the fact that digest cycles affect the entire scope hierarchy. In other words, `$scope.$apply()` triggers all watchers from top to bottom.

Once the application is complex enough (it always depends on client and app, but the crucial point is often estimated at ~1000 watchers for simplicity), it starts to become unresponsive on digests.

A good way to optimize this is to encapsulate directive changes and keep directives from announcing digests on root scope, unless global digest is the desired behaviour. In this case `$scope.$digest()` may be called instead of `$scope.$apply()` (the fundamental difference between those two is that the latter [calls `$rootScope.$digest()`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.7/src/ng/rootScope.js#L1073)).

Here comes the difference. `scope.$parent.$watch(...)` watcher won't be triggered on  `$scope.$digest()` but it will be on `$scope.$apply()`. And it shows why directive isolation is important and why referring parent scope from child is bad habit.

Another unpleasant surprise is that `scope.$parent.$watch(...)` may cause memory leaks. If the element that owns `scope` was destroyed, the watcher won't be cleaned up automatically. And it will refer to detached `element`, preventing the object from being garbage-collected.

`$scope.$parent` is evil.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. What `$element` is does not change because you are capturing the `$element` reference that you have in that scope (JavaScript scope, not Angular scope) when you are declaring that function.

Now if you did something like this:

```
scope.$parent.$watch('$element.isVisible()', myFuncUponVisibleChange);
```

Then that would be totally different, because at that point you would be referencing the `$element` from the parent scope, not the other scope.